# Copy element text to clipboard aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to copy the text of an element on my aspx website and can't get it to work.
I want to click a button and let it copy the text of my lblFileLink to the clipboard.
notice: this page is using a masterpage
here is my code:

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblFileLink" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy link" OnClientClick="copyToClipboard()" />
    <script>
        function copyToClipboard() {
            var element = document.getElementById("lblFileLink")
            var $temp = $("<input>");
            $("body").append($temp);
            $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $temp.remove();
            return false
        }
    </script>
```

I want it to do that before postback so with javascrip/jquery

Edit: I noticed the id was different on the site itself so now my code is this:

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblFileLink" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy link" OnClientClick="copyToClipboard('#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblFileLink')" />
    <script>
        function copyToClipboard(element) {
            var $temp = $("<input>");
            $("body").append($temp);
            $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $temp.remove();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy link" 
OnClientClick="copyToClipboard()" />
```

because when using asp.net controllers run at server it post back to server.

using button html tag.

```
<button id="btnCopy" click="copyToClipboard()">Copy link</button>
```

or you can do this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy link" 
     OnClientClick="copyToClipboard(); return false;" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found another solution which i liked more, I am implementing the onclientclick double event you used at the third option.